# JS : Undefined value after assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem I can't solve. I have easy 'for loop' :

```
for(var i=0; i < self.tableData.length; i++) {
     var row = self.tableData[i];
     $(".time").text(formatTimeSince(row.time));
}
```

Console send me an error :

```
TypeError: row is undefined
$(".time").html(formatTimeSince(row.time));
```

I checked into Firefox/Opera/Chrome Debugger and I have `Object` into `row` after assigned.

```
 row     Object { time=1409141350969, amount=3, price=10, więcej...}
         time             1409141350969
         amount             3
         price              10
         currencyBought     "USD"
         currencySold       "EUR"
         exchangeRate       1
```

Function `formatTimeSince()` preparing an time view for displaying.

I tried a lot of methods but It still doesn't work.

Comment: Where does that code appear?

Comment: does this error happen in all browsers?

Comment: If you add abreakpoint to the line that errors and inspect row what does it contain? - Plus your code updates the same thing multiple times, you'll only see the last value.... You should probably declare row outside of the loop

Comment: are you sure you're looking at the right part of your code for the error? `$(".time").html(formatTimeSince(row.time));` is the error but you show `$(".time").text(formatTimeSince(row.time));` and `text!==html`

Comment: @Pointy This code is appear when I update an "Offer Table". And I want update time since adding offer.

Comment: @Nick Yes, but in Chrome and Opera looks like this :
    "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined"

Comment: @DavidB The last 'code field' into my anser show what row contain. Declare row outside of the loop doesn't work.

Comment: @SoLiD i presume self.tableData is an array?

Comment: @andrew My fault. In code i have     $('.time').text(formatTimeSince(row.time));

Comment: @andrew yes, it's array which contain all displaying offers.

Comment: @SoLiD I can only suggest you post more of your code, there is no reason why that loop should result in an undefined `row`

Comment: Show the code around the `for` loop. How exactly does the array get filled?

Comment: I noticed that when I add breakpoint on line with row assigned It's working (in next line row is normaly value I want). But when I add breakpoint at once to the line with "$(".time")..." it doesn't work. Maybe this is due to asynchronous character of JS ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `self.tableData[i]` must be `undefined` at some point and is assigned to row. I can't see any other way.

Comment: if `tableData` is "filled" asynchronously, this loop should be in some sort of callback that is invoked when the async operation is complete

Comment: @Nick this table is creating after first use of this function.

Comment: Maybe the $(".time") is selecting the row.time itself. So, it's some loop. $(".time") looks too generic. I would expect $(row).find(".time").text(formatTimeSince(row.time));

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek it's doesn't work too. But I noticed that the loop should go to table.lenght but It's going to "table.lenght+1". And on last loop running this error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED.

My friend setup `tableData.lenght = 20`. And when I had for example six elements my for loop still running to 20. When `i=tableData.lenght+1` he throw an error and reset loop.